# ログインフォームでのログイン時、ボタンを押しても null が返されてしまう

Tags: java, servlet, jdbc

Eclipseを使用してログインフォームを作成したのですが、useridとpassを入力してログインボタンを押してもnullが返されてしまいます。
データベースにデータは登録できているのですがなぜかできないです。

DAOクラス

```
package dao;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

import bean.User;

public class LoginDao {

    //JDBC接続情報
    public static String RDB_DRIVE = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/logindb";
    public static String USER ="root";
    public static String PASS = "root";

    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    //JDBC接続メソッド
    public Connection getConnection(){
        try{
            Class.forName(RDB_DRIVE);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
            return con;

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    //新規登録メソッド(パスワードはハッシュ化)
    public void InsertUser(String userid, String pass){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement smt = null;

        try{
            con = getConnection();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO loginfo (userid,pass,salt) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            //ランダムなソルトを生成
            byte[] salt = generateSalt();

            //ソルトを含めてパスワードをハッシュ化
            String hashedPassword = hashPassword(pass,salt);

            smt.setString(1, userid);
            smt.setString(2, hashedPassword);
            smt.setBytes(3, salt);

            smt.executeUpdate();

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }finally{
            try{
                if(smt != null){
                    smt.close();
                }
                if(con != null){
                    con.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //ランダムなソルト生成
    private byte[] generateSalt(){
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

    //ハッシュ化パスワード生成
    private String hashPassword(String pass, byte[] salt){
        //反復回数
        int iterations = 1000;
        //ソルトを含めてSHA-256でハッシュ化
        String saltedPassword = pass + new String(salt);
        String hashedPassword = saltedPassword;

        for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++){
            hashedPassword = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(hashedPassword);
        }
        //Apache Commons Codeを使用してSHA-256でハッシュ化
        return hashedPassword;
    }

    //ユーザー情報削除メソッド
    public void deleteUser(String userid, String pass){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement smt = null;

        try{
            con = getConnection();
            String sql = "DELETE FROM loginfo WHERE userid = ? AND pass = ?";
            smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            smt.setString(1, userid);
            smt.setString(2, pass);
            smt.executeUpdate();

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }finally{
            try{
                if(smt != null){
                    smt.close();
                }
                if(con != null){
                    con.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //ユーザー情報検索メソッド
    public User select(String userid, String pass){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement smt = null;
        User user = new User();

        try{
            con = getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM loginfo WHERE userid = ? AND pass = ?";
            smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            smt.setString(1, userid);
            smt.setString(2, pass);

            ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                user.setUserid(rs.getString("userid"));
                user.setPass(rs.getString("pass"));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Retrieved user: " + user.getUserid() + ", Pass: " + user.getPass());
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }finally{
            try{
                if(smt != null){
                    smt.close();
                }
                if(con != null){
                    con.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

BEANクラス

```
package bean;

public class User {

    private String userid;
    private String pass;

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }


}
```

サーブレット

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

import bean.User;
import dao.LoginDao;

public class SelectServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException,IOException{

        //エンコーディング設定
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html;utf-8");

        //パラメーター取得
        String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        //Userオブジェクト、Daoオブジェクト生成
        LoginDao logdao = new LoginDao();
        User user = new User();

        //検索メソッド呼び出し
        user = logdao.select(userid, pass);

        try{
            if(user.getUserid() != null && checkPassword(pass,user.getPass())){
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/complete.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else if(userid.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty()){
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //パスワードの一致判定を行うメソッド
    private boolean checkPassword(String inputPassword,String hashedPasswordFromDB){
        String hashedPasswordFromInput = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(inputPassword);
        return hashedPasswordFromDB.equals(hashedPasswordFromInput);

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException,IOException{

        doGet(request,response);
    }
}
```

データベースに追加するサーブレット

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import dao.LoginDao;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,IOException{

        //エンコーディング設定
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html;utf-8");

        //パラメータ取得
        String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        String message ="";
        //入力が空であればエラー表示
        if(userid == null || userid.isEmpty() || pass == null ||  pass.isEmpty()){
            message = "入力してください";
        }

        //daoオブジェクト生成
        LoginDao login = new LoginDao();

        if(message.isEmpty()){
            //登録メソッド呼び出し
            login.InsertUser(userid,pass);
            //リクエストスコープ
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/userset.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            //入力パラメータメッセージをセット
            request.setAttribute("message", message);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/newuser.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException,IOException{
        doPost(request,response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LoginDao.InsertUser()`では、(引数の)パスワードをハッシュ化してDBに格納しているのに対し、`LoginDao.select()`では、(引数の)パスワードをそのまま検索条件にしているので、一致するものが見つけられないように見受けました。

＃(ログインボタンを押すとおそらくSelectServletが呼ばれると予想しましたが)サーブレット内でハッシュ化してはいないように見受けました。

検索するときもパスワードをハッシュ化すれば良いと思います。
いかがでしょうか?